# Does PHP have built-in array function to remove specific key and return removed?

Tags: php

I want something that works like `array_pop()` or `array_shift()`, so it returns the removed element, but I'd like to specify by key which element to remove.

Example:

```
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3]; 
$removed = array_remove($arr, 'b');

print_r($arr); // Outputs: Array(['a'] => 1, ['c'] => 3 )
print_r($removed); // Outputs: 2
```

Now I'am using

```
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3]; 
$removed = $arr['b'];
unset($arr['b']);
```

Comment: If you go to the manual, you can [go through the existing array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and check if any of them does what you want. There aren't that many...

Comment: What's wrong with your current version?  As it's only 2 lines long, it's hardly bloating your code.

Comment: No but it would be trivial to make array_remove. https://3v4l.org/lhFMI

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array

Comment: I believe your solution is readable, the most performant and that there is not a reserved function for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

array_splice() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php
Omit replacement.

Comment: That won't work with hash maps and the removed value is not returned.
The second argument must be an integer and the return type is an array.