# Delete an element of array in function

Tags: php, function, array-unset

I'm using some functions to delete vars. My code is like:

```
<?
$arr['var1'] = 'Hello';
$arr['var2'] = 'world';
function foo(){
    global $arr;
    unset($arr['var2']);
} 
foo();
```

But in the PHP manual:

> To unset() a global variable inside of a function, then use the
>   **$GLOBALS** array to do so:

```
unset($GLOBALS['arr']['var2']);
```

*Doesn't unset anything because `$GLOBALS['arr']['var2']` doesn't exist.
I only want to unset GLOBAL array element inside function.*

**It exists, because GLOBALS are supervariable** and it has everything other var has.

**edit:**

I tried to do it but after I try to call `foo()` then i try to `print_r($arr)`
it show both var1 and var2, and if I try `print_r($GLOBALS['arr']['var2'])` it show undefined index.... Maybe it's be config...

**edit2**

I mistyped it in my script. So it's working...

Full working code:

```
<?
$arr['var1'] = 'Hello';
$arr['var2'] = 'world';
function foo(){
    global $arr;
    unset($GLOBALS['arr']['var2']);
} 
foo();
```

Comment: _don't unset anything, because $GLOBALS['arr']['var2']  don't exist._ Sure it exists: `print_r($GLOBALS);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver getting undefined index if I try it...

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong https://3v4l.org/4FXkE

Comment: Your function will work ___only you have to call the function___

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add it... I know...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: You can paste the code into any online PHP evaluator and it obviously works https://eval.in/980279 or http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf946cd94d9f16e392fe4cb00c1375792a20da7f

Comment: Something odd here. __Please show us the full code and ALL the error messages__

Comment: It wasn't inside php code, but in conf... I don't have any **OTHER** errors/warnings..

Comment: @DanB.Can you clear my confusion about **I tried to do it but after I try to call foo() then i try to print_r($arr) it show both var1 and var2**, Because on my answer I didn't find this thing :) Have you tried the way I tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variable by reference:

```
$arr['var1'] = 'Hello';
$arr['var2'] = 'world';
function foo(&$a){
    unset($a['var2']);
}
foo($arr);
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0):

`unset($GLOBALS['arr']['var2']);` is correct.

see here https://3v4l.org/rCN5h

```
<?php
$arr['var1'] = 'Hello';
$arr['var2'] = 'world';
function foo(){
unset($GLOBALS['arr']['var2']);
}
var_dump($arr);
foo();
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: @DanB. it does work, check again. or just check my link.