# Laravel - How to remove item in array do not use the loop

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
array:1 [
  "arrays" => array:2 [
    "hihi" => array:4 [
      "one" => "14000"
      "two" => "15000"
      "three" => "16000"
    ]
    "huhu" => array:4 [
      "one" => "69997"
      "two" => "72000"
      "three" => "77000"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to remove item `two` from the given array:

**Output**

```
array:1 [
  "arrays" => array:2 [
    "hihi" => array:4 [
      "one" => "14000"
      "three" => "16000"
    ]
    "huhu" => array:4 [
      "one" => "69997"
      "three" => "77000"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I tried with `array_pluck` but had a problem with `hihi` and `huhu`. Hoping to find a solution without the use of a loop.

**Note:** `hihi` and `huhu` are both dynamic arrays.

Comment: You realize you have an array INSIDE another array? I think you should do `unset($array[0][1]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Why without a loop?  If hihi and huhu aren't constant, you'd need a loop.

Comment: Do you use laravel? `array_pluck` is a helper from it

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Laravel, then it has a helper method, [`array_forget()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-array-forget):

```php
array_forget($array, 'arrays.hihi.two');

array_forget($array, 'arrays.huhu.two');
```

Comment: hihi, huhu is dynamic data

Comment: Then you’re going to need to iterate.

Comment: What function is this: array_forget ($array, 'arrays.*.two'); in laravel or php?

Comment: @TrầnNgọcĐức Laravel. I mentioned in my answer and added a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v) {
    unset($v["two"]);
    return $v;
}, $array["arrays"]);
```

https://3v4l.org/AeXrO

Comment: I want to find no way to use loops

Comment: @TrầnNgọcĐức  If your data is dynamic you can't achieve this without iterating. Maybe elaborate on why you need it without iterations so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    'arrays' => array(
        'hihi' => array(
            'one' => '14000',
            'two' => '15000',
            'three' => '16000'
        ),
        'huhu' => array(
            'one' => '69997',
            'two' => '72000',
            'three' => '77000'
        ),
    )
);
```

You can use `array_map` function to remove the item **`two`** from the array, and by using closure `use ($key)` you can also perform some actions on the element of an array. [Read `array_map` in detail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$key = 'two';
$result = array(
    'arrays' => array_map(
        function($item) use ($key) {
            unset($item[$key]);
            return $item;
        }, 
        $array["arrays"]
    )
);

print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
[arrays] => Array
(
    [hihi] => Array
    (
        [one] => 14000
        [three] => 16000
    )
    [huhu] => Array
    (
        [one] => 69997
        [three] => 77000
    )
)
```

## Updated Answer

```
// First array key of the given array which is "arrays"
$getParentKey = array_keys($array); 

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => arrays
)

// Then, get all values inside "arrays" array which is given below
$getValues = $array[$getParentKey[0]];

Output:
Array
(
    [hihi] => Array
    (
        [one] => 14000
        [two] => 15000
        [three] => 16000
    )
    [huhu] => Array
    (
        [one] => 69997
        [two] => 72000
        [three] => 77000
    )
)

// At last, get "hihi" and "huhu" keys
$getInnerKeys = array_keys($getValues);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => hihi
    [1] => huhu
)

// And finally, just unset the items from the array
// "$getInnerKeys[0]" means "hihi" and "$getInnerKeys[1]" means "huhu"
unset($array[$getParentKey[0]][$getInnerKeys[0]]['two']);
unset($array[$getParentKey[0]][$getInnerKeys[1]]['two']);
```

**Complete Code**

```
$getParentKey = array_keys($array);
$getValues = $array[$getParentKey[0]];
$getInnerKeys = array_keys($getValues);

unset($array[$getParentKey[0]][$getInnerKeys[0]]['two']);
unset($array[$getParentKey[0]][$getInnerKeys[1]]['two']);


print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
[arrays] => Array
(
    [hihi] => Array
    (
        [one] => 14000
        [three] => 16000
    )
    [huhu] => Array
    (
        [one] => 69997
        [three] => 77000
    )

)
```

Without using `foreach` loop, you can use `array_keys` to remove item from the array.

## Another Option

You can also use recursive function, and the recursive function is a function that calls *itself*, and the function calling will stop on the *condition*. Read [PHP Recursive Functions](https://www.elated.com/articles/php-recursive-functions/) more in detail.

In below code example, the `$count` and `$array` are passing to the function once then function is calling *itself* and the ending point is based on the *condition*.

```
$count = 0;
$array = array(
    'arrays' => array(
        'hihi' => array(
            'one' => '14000',
            'two' => '15000',
            'three' => '16000'
        ),
        'huhu' => array(
            'one' => '69997',
            'two' => '72000',
            'three' => '77000'
        ),
    )
);

incrementCount($count, $array);

function incrementCount($count, $array) {
    $getParentKey = array_keys($array);
    $getValues = $array[$getParentKey[0]];
    $getInnerKeys = array_keys($getValues);
    $countInnerKeys = count($getInnerKeys);

    if ($count < $countInnerKeys) {
        unset($array[$getParentKey[0]][$getInnerKeys[$count]]['two']);

        incrementCount($count + 1, $array);
    }
    else {
        print_r($array);
        return;
    }
}
```

Calling the function and unsetting two from the array until `$countInnerKeys` not reached (means `$count` reached to **huhu** key).

Comment: thank you, but i want to find solution without using loop: D, maybe this is not feasible

Comment: @Trần Ngọc Đức, please check the updated answer and what do you think still not feasible :D

Comment: btw, I'm not sure that hihi and huhu are dynamic keys so that's why I unset "two" from both of them, one by one as you can see above!

Comment: @TranDuc if last solution makes sense then it's great otherwise you need to iterate, but what's the purpose of not using loops? Could you please explain?