# PHP: Delete Value of Array with Dynamic Key

Tags: php, arrays

A bit unusual use-case but maybe you can help:

I have the keys of an value as a separate array. It is pretty easy to get the value of the array with it like this:

```
function whatEver(){

    $array = array(
        0 => array( 'other' ),
        1 => array(
            0 => array( 'other' ),
            1 => array( 'value' )
        ),
    );

    $keys = array(
        0 => '1',
        1 => '1'
    );

    $result = $array;

    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        $result = $result[$key];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This will return the correct array/value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value
)
```

But what if I want to delete this value (like unset($array[1][1])) from the original array and return the original $array without the value?

Comment: Do you want the Key and the value gone, or just the value?

Comment: I want the key and the value gone and return the original array without the value.

Comment: Did `unset($array[$key][$key]);` fail or something?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: `$array` is dynamic and I don't know the structure. `$keys` is dynamic, too, and can have an unknown amount of values. That is why I cannot do a simple unset($array[$key][$key]). Otherwise I could also easily get the value without a foreach-loop. So I don't think that this is a duplicate. But please correct me if I am missing something...

Comment: Please take a look at my library phpintegration: https://github.com/ksamborski/phpintegration/blob/master/PHPIntegration/Utils/ArrayHelper.php It removes element from array the way you want (method unsetPath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this to work for an arbitrary number of keys, you'll need to assign `$result` by reference on each iteration, and unset at the final step:

```
$result = &$array;
$last = array_pop($keys);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  $result = &$result[$key];
}

unset($result[$last]);
```

Note that you need to treat the final key slightly differently (the one stored in `$last`). If you just set a reference down to the last level, the unset will only remove the reference, not the actual element.

See https://3v4l.org/0a5Nv

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `unset($array[$key])`? This will delete that key out of the array along with whatever value is associated with it.

This is probably a duplicate of: [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: the problem is, that both (`$array` and `$key`) are dynamic and you don't know the length and structure. If I `unset($array[$key]))` then I will always delete the key in the first level of the multidimensional array. But it might be in the 10th level, so I need the key path to delete it like `array[$key][$key][$key][...]` or whatever. This is why I am struggling ... :)