# How to remove multiple array with value 0 in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple array having the last index with 0 value and needs to remove that specific index. how can I do that in PHP? Thanks

[image: array that index 3 has 0 value]

Comment: Pleas share what you have tried so far and why this did not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried anything? A loop and `array_filter` would work.

Comment: do you always need to remove the index `2` or sometimes its some other index?

Comment: Red Bottle, No its not .. it can be 3, 4 but its alwas the last index.

Comment: You can user array_filter function : 

array_filter($arr); // removing blank, null, false, 0 (zero) values

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a Laravel way of doing it, you could achieve this with Collections.

```
$data = [
    'edu_country' => ['1', '11', '0'], 
    'edu_grade' => ['1', '1', '0']
]; 

return collect($data)->map(function($value) {
    return collect($value)->reject(function($value, $key) {
        return $value === '0'; 
    })->toArray();
})->toArray();
```

There might be an easier way of doing this with a Collection as well. I need to research a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter`. Reference : [php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
// Select only non-zero value indices
$newArray = array_filter($originalArray, function ($a) {
            return $a != 0;
            });
```

Comment: This does not work since it is a multidimensional array so your $a is the nested array and not the value "0"

Comment: How to do that in such case?