# Use array_splice before foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm using [php simple dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

I'm trying to clean up an array prior to a foreach loop, my code so far:

```
$html = file_get_html('test/php/refs.calendar.html');

$links = array();

foreach ($html->find('ul') as $ul) {

        $links[] = $ul->plaintext ;    

}

echo '<pre>',print_r($links, 1),'</pre>'; 


prints out:

Array
(
    [0] => bla bla
    [1] => more bla bla 
    [2] => some text
    [3] => some more text
    [4] => some more text
    [5] => some more text
)

prior to foreach loop i tried:

$links[] = array_splice($html->find('ul'), 1, 2) ;
```

I would like to get rid of array[1](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and [2] before the loop, I think i'm getting objects and arrays in a twizzle, any ideas guys?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're trying to remove an element (or 2) from the array. This popular topic was addressed here: [Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array) It discusses several ways to delete array elements using `unset()`, `array_splice()` and some others. Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to splice before sending into the array, do it after:

```
    array_splice($links, 0,2);
    print_r($links);
```

or unset:

```
    unset($links[0], $links[1]);
    print_r($links);
```

Comment: Not quite, array[1] and [2] were deleted, not [0[ and [1] weird?? but unset($links[0]);
unset($links[1]); worked

Comment: `array_splice($links, 0, 2);`

Comment: The 1 parameter represents the first entry, which would be [0]. Glad you managed.

Comment: Nope, exact opposite, print out 0 and 1 i.e. the keys I don't want

Comment: unset can have multiple arguments, I tried unset($links[0], [1]); but syntax error. What is correct syntax?

Comment: I updated it, now it should work, the mistake was when assigning the splite to $links

Comment: Updated with the right unset syntax, I usually find the PHP documentation very useful when I need some to correct syntax. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php