# Remove element inside array in MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this structure in mongoDB and I want to remove all "Vespertino" elements using PHP:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("5a186d574b23328df3be"),"monday": [
"Vespertino",
"Matutino"],"tuesday": [
"Test1",
"Matutino"],"wednesday": [
"Vespertino",
"Test2"],"thursday": ["Test3","Matutino"],"friday": ["Vespertino","Matutino"],"saturday": ["Matutino"],"sunday": [],"id":"30334798","c_code": "my_company"}
```

I was trying to get results in first place and then remove the element but I get only null results, this was my attempt until now:

```
$query_shifts = array('c_code'=>"my_company","wednesday.Vespertino"=> array('$exists' => true));
```

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array , try to use array_slice or unset

Comment: oh no no @MiguelCruz, I need to remove the elements from MongoDB document. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongodb query is :

```
db.CollectionName.update({"_id": ObjectId("5a186d574b23328df3be")}, {
    {$pull: {monday: "Vespertino", tuesday: "Vespertino", wednesday: "Vespertino", thursday: "Vespertino", friday: "Vespertino", saturday: "Vespertino", sunday: "Vespertino"} },
    { multi: true }
});
```

in PHP :

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->update(["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("5a186d574b23328df3be")], [$pull => ['monday' => "Vespertino", 'tuesday' => "Vespertino", 'wednesday' => "Vespertino", 'thursday' => "Vespertino", 'friday' => "Vespertino", 'saturday' => "Vespertino", 'sunday' => "Vespertino"]);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('dbName.CollectionName', $bulk);
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks! your solution works perfect! This is my final code in PHP:                       $r = $col->update(array('c_code'=>"my_company"),array('$pull'=>array('monday'=>"vespertino",'tuesday'=>"vespertino",'wednesday'=>"vespertino",'thursday'=>"vespertino",'friday'=>"vespertino",'saturday'=>"vespertino",'sunday'=>"vespertino")),array('multiple' => true) );

Comment: Yes; Your final code is correct for remove all of the 'vespertino' items from all documents of your collection.