# Delete a state from nested JSON in php (Laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a column with json structure:

```
[{"id":3},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]}]}]
```

The value of id that comes with request is 4.

How can i delete id of value 4 and his children ?

I except output like this:

```
[{"id":3}]
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? What did you tried ?

Comment: I except output like this: [{"id":3}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter of json_decode to get a php array and work with php built-in functions.

```
$string = '[{"id":3},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]}]}]';
$result = array_filter(json_decode($string, true), function($elem){return $elem['id']!=4;});
```

array_filter keeps only the elements for which the callback function returns true, so this keeps all elements where `id` is not 4