# how to remove array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have array in this structure, and I want delete `item[6]` from array.

I used `unset($arrayname[6])` in php but it's not working. Any help? Is there any way I can remove element [6] from array?

```
 array(2) {
            [6]=>
            array(2) {
              ["id"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["day"]=>
              string(6) "Monday"
            }
            [7]=>
            array(2) {
              ["id"]=>
              string(1) "2"
              ["day"]=>
              string(7) "Tuesday"

            }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an element from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/deleting-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working?  Please dump the result (your array) after your unset.

Comment: Are you unsetting the item from the correct array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unset()` function which removes the element from an array and then use `array_values()` function which indexes the array numerically.

```
$array2 = {{array of array}}
// remove item at index 6 which is 'for' 
unset($array2[6]); 
// Print modified array 
var_dump($array2); 
// Re-index the array elements 
$arr2 = array_values($array2); 
//Print re-indexed array 
var_dump($array2);
```

This solution will work, please check and let me know.

Comment: Why re-index the items with array_values?  The keys may be important.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you would expect:

```
<?php
$days =
    array (
        6 => 
        array (
            'id' => 1,
            'day' => 'Mon',
        ),
        7 => 
        array (
            'id' => 2,
            'day' => 'Tue',
        )
    );

unset($days[6]);
var_export($days);
```

Output:

```
array (
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'day' => 'Tue',
  ),
)
```