# How to remove specific data from list with id in firebase laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error
**Error: Call to a member function remove() on array in file**

[image: Getting this Array]

How can I remove specific data from array where clinic_id matches?

```
    $factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount($app)
        ->withDatabaseUri('db');
    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
    $reference = $database->getReference('list_notification')->getValue();

   foreach ($reference as $ref){
        if($ref["clinic_id"] === $clinicId){
            $ref->remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're calling a methos on an array !! what is the answer you're expecting to get ? you can check the variables nature yourself using some `dd($variable)`

Comment: Yes, But I'm getting array what I can do to remove specific array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting an element from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/deleting-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount($app)
        ->withDatabaseUri('https://dental-notification-efd83-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
    $database = $factory->createDatabase();
    $references = $database->getReference("list_notification")->getValue();

    foreach ($references as $key){
        if($key["clinic_id"] == $clinicId){
            $database->getReference('list_notification/'. $key["unique_id"])->remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an element from an array as any variable, use `unset()`

```
$reference = $database->getReference('list_notification')->getValue();

foreach ($reference as $key => $ref){
    if($ref["clinic_id"] === $clinicId){
        $database->getReference('list_notification/'.$key)->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: We have to add remove method of firebase to remove specific array.

Comment: @DaniyalMughees does this one answer your needs ? if not why ?

Comment: Where I have to place remove() method of firebase to remove specific array?

Comment: @DaniyalMughees maybe this is what you're looking for (edited the answer)