# How to remove value from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

This is my php output:

```
Array ( [hbon] => 819dc5022135e9cfa06c5a2cd99324f5d94c8d54bb9050215cf8073a53c54c38 [host] => aHhzZGV2Lm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4 
        [ids] => Array ( [0] => 4030248026278 ) 
        [locale] => en-PK 
        [session] => b109efd9b4948eced607e4a5245dbe3dc05e593dab99c58fbc98998c44439aaf     
        [web] => iuhxsdev.com 
        [timestamp] => 1628669451 )
```

I removed hbon using this code

```
array_diff_key($params, array('hbon' => ''));
```

and it removed the hbon and result is

```
Array ( [host] => aHhzZGV2Lm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4 
        [ids] => Array ( [0] => 4030248026278 ) 
        [locale] => en-PK 
        [session] => b109efd9b4948eced607e4a5245dbe3dc05e593dab99c58fbc98998c44439aaf
        [web] => iuhxsdev.com 
        [timestamp] => 1628669451 )
```

I also want to remove [ids] but it is in array, how to remove [ids] completely?

Comment: Where did the `host` key come from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting an element from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/deleting-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `ids` from the array by using:

```php
unset($array['ids']);
```

where `$array` is the variable of the array where subarray `ids` is stored in.

Answer (score 1):

to remove an element in an array use : unset($your_array[key]);