# why when I have been trying for some time to create columns in a table in a phpMyadmin database, does it not work?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a database under phpmyadmin and add fields to it. but when I choose the number of columns of a table that I create, it gives me a single column, and even until this column after being filled with its properties, the field registration does not take.

except before I didn't have this problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/deleting-an-element-from-an-array-in-php this may help

Comment: @lozo his problem is about a database, not array manipulation

Comment: @Valere please elaborate on your problem and walk us through the steps you took so we can try to help

Comment: @A First I launch my local server, then I open phpmyadmin in localhost then I create a new database, and I add a table, I want to insert columns to my table but phpmyadmin does not succeed in adding fields to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem, but after deleting the installation files and reinstalling, the problem disappeared