# I get a different behavior after unset() elements

Tags: php, arrays

I get a strange behavior when I remove data from my array with unset

```
$array = [['name' => "pepe"], ['name' => 'marta']];
unset($array[0]);
unset($array[1]);
```

And I append more objects to the array

```
$array[] = $value1;
$array[] = $value2;
echo json_encode($array);
```

When I convert $array into an object I get this key values insted of index values

```
{"2":{"name":"mario"},"3":{"name":"hector"}}
```

Expected output

```
[{"name":"mario"},{"name":"hector"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting an element from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/deleting-an-element-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because php unset doesn't reduce the length of the array, it just empty the given key.

Since it doesn't change the length, whe. You do `$array[] = something` you continue incrementing the index, creating the 2 and 3 index you are seeing.

When you do `json_encode`, since the keys doesn't start from zero (or aren't contiguous), it need to represent this array as an object.

Exemplifying:

```
$var1 = [1 => 'a', 3 => 'b'];
```

Can only be serialized to

```
{"1": "a", "3": "b"}
```

Because you can't define the index of an array item using JSON.

## Solution

You can still use `unset()`, but you need to get only array values using the `array_values()` function:

```
$array = [['name' => "pepe"], ['name' => 'marta']];
unset($array[0]);
unset($array[1]);

$array[] = $value1;
$array[] = $value2;
// $array is now [2=>$value1, 3=>$value2]

$array = array_values($array);
// $array is now [$value1, $value2]

echo json_encode($array);
// Now the json outputs as expected by you: ["value1", "value2"]
```